# Unusual texify error

Tags: pdftex, texify

I recently updated all my packages in MiKTeX, and now have an unusual crash when I build a file.

Straight from ST2, I get the `pdflatex.exe has stopped working` error, but the pdf generates without an issue. To try and debug my issue, I tried compiling from the command line:

`texify` (no args) crashes (`texify.exe has stopped working`)

`texify text.tex` crashes (`latex.exe has stopped working, texify: latex failed for some reason (see log file)`), and does not produce a pdf

`pdftex test.tex` tells me that `\documentclass{article}` is an undefined control sequence

`pdflatex test.tex` builds without an issue

I am using MiKTeX version 2.9.5700

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
MWE
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `pdftex` error is expected. The `texify text.tex` error is not included in your post - it is in the log file and you don't tell us what it is. Is `texify` without any arguments expected to do anything? If so, what? Is there a log file? What is 'ST2'?

Comment: Often crashes (and other misbehaviour) are caused by stale/wrong version intermediate files. Clean them out and try again.

Comment: ST2 is sublime text 2. Sorry, I forgot to mention that the most annoying part of the error is that the log files for the crashing component always seem to be empty.

Comment: I think I reinstalled miktex and the error went away